# How to use the value in one table to count results in another table?

Tags: sql, join, count

I want to add a new column on my SQL query that will count the number of times a value on the row appears in a different table.

For example, let's say I have these two separate tables.

**Table Name: Table_A**

```
Id   | Coach  | Team_Color  | Team_Number
------------------------------------------
001  | Jane   | Orange      | 121
002  | Frank  | Purple      | 232
003  | Tim    | Red         | 343
```

**Table Name: Table_B**

```
Id   | Team_Number | Player_Name  
----------------------------------
901  | 121         | Jimmy  
902  | 121         | Wesley  
903  | 121         | Samantha
904  | 121         | Wendy
905  | 232         | Tim  
906  | 232         | Sean  
907  | 343         | Andrew
908  | 343         | Erik
909  | 343         | Sarah  
910  | 343         | Allison  
911  | 343         | Desmond
912  | 343         | Kathryn
```

I want to end up with something like this:

```
Id   | Coach  | Team_Color  | Team_Number | Player Count
--------------------------------------------------------
001  | Jane   | Orange      | 121         | 4
002  | Frank  | Purple      | 232         | 2
003  | Tim    | Red         | 343         | 6
```

The new column called "Player Count" is referencing the Team_Number value in Table_A, and counting the number of instances found on Table_B. How would I compose this into one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to your Problem:

```
SELECT A.Id, A.Coach, A.Team_Color,A.Team_Number,Count(B.Id) AS Player_Count
FROM Table_A AS A
INNER JOIN Table_B B
ON A.Team_Number = B.Team_Number
GROUP BY A.Id, A.Coach, A.Team_Color,A.Team_Number;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Id  Coach   Team_Color  Team_Number  Player_Count
1   Jane    Orange       121          4
2   Frank   Purple       232          2
3   Tim     Red          343          6
```

Follow the link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c6da4/1

**EXPLAINATION:**

In your problem, you have to use `JOIN` to join the two tables on a common Column i.e.`Team_Number`. Now after Joining you will get a result like this:

```
Id  Coach  Team_Color  Team_Number  Id   Team_Number    Player_Name
1   Jane    Orange       121        901    121           Jimmy
1   Jane    Orange       121        902    121           Wesley
1   Jane    Orange       121        903    121           Samantha
1   Jane    Orange       121        904    121           Wendy
2   Frank   Purple       232        905    232           Tim
2   Frank   Purple       232        906    232           Sean
3   Tim     Red          343        907    343           Andrew
3   Tim     Red          343        908    343           Erik
3   Tim     Red          343        909    343           Sarah
3   Tim     Red          343        910    343           Allison
3   Tim     Red          343        911    343           Desmond
3   Tim     Red          343        912    343           Kathryn
```

Now Use aggregate function `COUNT` on above Result to get the final result.

Comment: add some info plz

Comment: Ya I am adding the info

Comment: If you find this answer useful please accept it as the answer.